# How to align form elements in justified manner?

Tags: html, css

I have designed the following HTML form :

```css
        div{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        fieldset{
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
        <body>

        <form action="index.html" method="post">
      
          <h1><center>FCNB Loan Request</center></h1>
        
          <center>
          <fieldset>
          
          <div>
            
          <label for="name">Branch Name and Code:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
          
    <label for="pfnumber">PF Number:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="pfnumber">
    
    <label for="cpname">Contact Person Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="cpname">
    
    <label for="cnumber">Contact Number:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="cnumber">
    
            </div>
    <hr> </hr>
    
    <!-- Input Fields -->
    
          <div>
          
    <label for="customer">Customer:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="customer">
    
    <label for="cif">CIF Number:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="cif">
    
    <label for="dfgt">If exporter, mention DGFT No. : </label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="dfgt">
    
    <label for="activity">Activity:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="activity">
    
          </div>
          
    <hr />

         </fieldset>
        </center>
        </form>
        </body>
```

The form elements are aligned in a centered manner without covering the width of the screen. I would like the form elements to be aligned in a "justified" manner, ie, to cover the width of the screen. How can this be done?

Comment: `<center>` is a deprecated/obsolete element and should no longer be used,

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following snippet to the style:

```
form label, form input {
   display: block;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

This will make your label and input tag take the full width of browser and also add some margin bottom to it.

```css
        div{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        fieldset{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        form label, form input {
           display: block;
           margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
```

```html
        <body>

        <form action="index.html" method="post">
      
          <h1><center>FCNB Loan Request</center></h1>
        
          <center>
          <fieldset>
          
          <div>
            
          <label for="name">Branch Name and Code:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
          
    <label for="pfnumber">PF Number:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="pfnumber">
    
    <label for="cpname">Contact Person Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="cpname">
    
    <label for="cnumber">Contact Number:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="cnumber">
    
            </div>
    <hr> </hr>
    
    <!-- Input Fields -->
    
          <div>
          
    <label for="customer">Customer:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="customer">
    
    <label for="cif">CIF Number:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="cif">
    
    <label for="dfgt">If exporter, mention DGFT No. : </label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="dfgt">
    
    <label for="activity">Activity:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="activity">
    
          </div>
          
    <hr />

         </fieldset>
        </center>
        </form>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi change `width:100%` with form elements,

```
 form label, form input {
       width:100%;
    }
```

```css
div{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        fieldset{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        form label, form input {
           width:100%;
        }
```

```html
 <body>

        <form action="index.html" method="post">
      
          <h1><center>FCNB Loan Request</center></h1>
        
          <center>
          <fieldset>
          
          <div>
            
          <label for="name">Branch Name and Code:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
          
    <label for="pfnumber">PF Number:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="pfnumber">
    
    <label for="cpname">Contact Person Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="cpname">
    
    <label for="cnumber">Contact Number:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="cnumber">
    
            </div>
    <hr> </hr>
    
    <!-- Input Fields -->
    
          <div>
          
    <label for="customer">Customer:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="customer">
    
    <label for="cif">CIF Number:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="cif">
    
    <label for="dfgt">If exporter, mention DGFT No. : </label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="dfgt">
    
    <label for="activity">Activity:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="activity">
    
          </div>
          
    <hr />

         </fieldset>
        </center>
        </form>
        </body>
```